Speaker issues - Autostart audio file - Script
So I have a Harman Kardon Onyx Studio 4 speaker.
It seems to hibernate itself if it doesn't detect a signal on the 3.5mm headphone jack for more than about a second (or if it's really low) which leads to it dropping in and out constantly. It doesn't do this when streaming over bluetooth.
I've made a 10hz sine wave tone that's 12 hours long and on repeat. This solves the problem.

Is this just really terrible design?

Am I doing any damage to the speakers by constantly running this tone in the background?

I'm currently manually starting this background tone every reboot. I'm looking for advice on how best to automate this. I'm using linux (ubuntu 24.04 but will be switching to strait up Debian soon) and guess it'll involve making a script that runs a command, then I stick that script in /etc/rc.local or something so it runs at boot. Is VLC or MPV the ideal choice for this or am I wasting resources?


Thanks!

This is an off topic hardware question. Best to address this with the speaker maker.

It's about a startup script and computer resource usage, everything else is just for flavor

You can use the command play or aplay followed by /path/to filename. Wav. If either of these command works, create a bash scripts that runs the command on a loop. Finally create a crontab that will start the bash script when the system reboots.



Is this just really terrible design?


Probably. Questions asking for opinions are off topic here.


Am I doing any damage to the speakers by constantly running this tone in the background?


Probably. Questions asking for opinions are off topic here.


I'm currently manually starting this background tone every reboot. I'm looking for advice on how best to automate this. I'm using linux
(ubuntu 24.04 but will be switching to strait up Debian soon) and
guess it'll involve making a script that runs a command, then I stick
that script in /etc/rc.local or something so it runs at boot. Is VLC
or MPV the ideal choice for this or am I wasting resources?


I would would write a bash script /home/totalconfusion/play10hz with the following contents:
#!/bin/bash
sleep 1m     # Wait for 1 minute
while :      # loop infinitely
do
    /usr/bin/aplay /full/path/to/sound-10hz.wav
done

Replace /full/path/to/sound-10hz.wav with the full path and name of the file.
The aplay is a basic command line audio file player that comes with Ubuntu.
Open the crontab with the command: crontab -e and add the following line at the bottom of the file:
@reboot /home/totalconfusion/play10hz

Save file and exit the crontab editor.
Note: When you are working with cron or crontab it is best to always provide the full path to all the files, scripts, and apps.
Next time your computer starts the sound should play continuously.
Hope this helps

Thanks heaps. Whats aplay?     /usr/bin/aplay   - Gotta assume it's a really basic audio player built in to ubuntu and stands for audio play

It is a basic command line audio file player. You can type man aplay to see more.
